# "backward.c", line 421: Failed to align audio to trancript

Tags: cmusphinx

My script was doing speech recognition training fine, until recently I tried to scale up to train on more data, now it output this error.

```
ERROR: "backward.c", line 421: Failed to align audio to trancript: final state of the search is not reached
```

What does that mean? What can I do about it?

It looks like the model training proceed anyway, but not sure if this is an error I can ignore.

I checked out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233480/sphinx-4-failed-to-align-audio-to-trancript), but I am pretty sure my audio are sampled at 16KHz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [documentation](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam#troubleshooting):

> Sometimes audio in your database doesn't match the transcription
>   properly. For example transcription file has the line “Hello world”
>   but in audio actually “Hello hello world” is pronounced. Training
>   process usually detects that and emits this message in the logs. If
>   there are too many such errors it most likely mean you misconfigured
>   something, for example you had a mismatch between audio and the text
>   caused by transcription reordering. Or input audio sample rate is wrong
>
> If there are few errors, you can
>   ignore them. You might want to edit the transcription file to put
>   there exact word which were pronounced, in the case above you need to
>   edit the transcription file and put “Hello hello world” on
>   corresponding line. You might want to filter such prompts because they
>   affect acoustic model quality. In that case you need to enable forced
>   alignment stage in training.